# My steam won't start!

Tags: unity, steam

Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

```
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0_client)
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/crash_20140420185934_1.dmp
/home/chidatn/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 755: 14713 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$PLATFORM/$STEAMEXE" "$@"
Bmv: cannot stat ‘/home/chidatn/.steam/registry.vdf’: No such file or directory
Installing bootstrap /home/chidatn/.local/share/Steam/bootstrap.tar.xz
Reset complete!
Restarting Steam by request...
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/chidatn/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0_client)
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/crash_20140420185936_1.dmp
/home/chidatn/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 755: 14839 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$PLATFORM/$STEAMEXE" "$@"
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
response: CrashID=bp-95884ef3-24c7-400d-9c3a-ef4af2140420
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
response: CrashID=bp-fd864c85-e5af-4d9f-8653-f766c2140420
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. For me it was a graphics driver issue.

My solution:

1. Open Additional Drivers
2. Select "Using X.Org X server(open source, tested)" driver.
3. Then go to Ubuntu Software Center and install Steam (steam-launcher).
4. Then change Graphic driver back.

All done.

Comment: I had a similar error messages so I tried this out and it worked. I   couldn't have thought that it was a graphics diver issue because Steam worked on one user account but not on another. I just installed the open-source driver then started Steam. I didn't have to re-install.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was completely the other way around - just installing proprietary Nvidia drivers (with restart after it) helped.

Comment: How to install them ?

Comment: I went to **Software&Updates** there I've chosen **Additional Drivers** then NVIDIA drivers, then Apply and then closed the window and rebooted. I'm using Ubuntu MATE 16.04 but i don't think it will be much different in original Ubuntu. Screenshot here http://storage7.static.itmages.com/i/17/0428/h_1493358357_6445389_72d577cd4b.png