# Steam problems in Ubuntu 15.04 x64

Tags: ati, steam, 15.04

Steam doesn't want to run in ubuntu 15.04. I have an ati graphics card (7870xt). I tried installing steam first and the proprietary drivers afterwards, and vice versa, removing steam files from ~/.steam and ~/.local/share/Steam and nothing helped.

Running steam from the terminal gives the following output:

```
Setting up Steam content in /home/lo-fi/.local/share/Steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0_client)
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/crash_20150425112336_1.dmp
/home/lo-fi/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 730: 11948 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
mv: cannot stat ‘/home/lo-fi/.steam/registry.vdf’: No such file or directory
Installing bootstrap /home/lo-fi/.local/share/Steam/bootstrap.tar.xz
Reset complete!
Restarting Steam by request...
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/lo-fi/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0_client)
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/crash_20150425112337_1.dmp
/home/lo-fi/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 730: 12076 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
response: CrashID=bp-8301f08b-196f-4c65-8be1-e80382150425
```

Any ideas are welcome.

EDIT: I installed libcurl3:i386 as per what @Velkan said. libcurl3 and curl were already installed. The output of the error changed somewhat, so I updated it above.

Comment: It complains about libcurl.so. Do you have it? Try to install `curl` or `libcurl3` package.

Comment: @Velkan I had it installed, but i went ahead and reinstalled it and also installed libcurl3:i386 for good measure. No deal, it still refuses to start, but i see a somewhat different output now. Updating the post.

Comment: Try the suggestions in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/536280/77449) and [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/452596/77449).

Answer (score 0):

Here are suggestions from other answers. The steps described in other answers are:

1. Follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/536280/77449) by @imolit:

> 1. uninstall your Nvidia or AMD driver
>
>    - I.e. `sudo apt-get purge fglrx*` or `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`
> 2. reboot
> 3. start Steam and let it update, while using the open drivers
> 4. reinstall your proprietary driver
> 5. and finally reboot again.

2. You can also try switching your driver to X.Org X server - see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/452596/77449) by @Michael:

> 1. Open Additional Drivers
> 2. Select "Using X.Org X server(open source, tested)" driver.
> 3. Then go to Ubuntu Software Center and install Steam (steam-launcher).
> 4. Then change Graphic driver back.