# Why wont Steam work on ubuntu?

Tags: steam

Whenever I click on the steam icon, nothing happens, all I get when running it in terminal is:

```
loger42@loger42-desktop:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0_client)
```

I had a problem previously with this related to graphics drivers, so I updated my graphics card drivers, and now this is all that I see in the terminal when I run steam. Before I installed the new drivers, the only other thing that appeared in the terminal was about missing drivers, such as nouveau and swrast.

I am running Ubuntu 15.04 64-bit

My hardware specs are:

- AMD 3.4Ghz processor
- NVIDIA GeForce 8400GS graphics card
- ASUS M5A97 LE R2.0 motherboard
- 4GB Dualstick memory
- 1TB WD Blue hard disk (Windows installation)
- 160GB (unkown brand) hard disk (Ubuntu installation)
- ATX power source

Comment: Can you post which graphics card driver you're using? See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/23240/77449) for how-to.

Comment: When I use the lshw -c video command, I get this:  configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0

Comment: Have you try to install ia-32libs? `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` . 
Steam needs a lot of 32 bits libraries according to this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/213864/installing-breakpad-exception-handler-for-appidsteam-while-trying-to-run-ste

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32z1 lib32ncurses5

E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate                                               <--------------     is what I get from that command

Comment: Yeah, try what @DanielSemblano suggested, and also, take a look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451293/my-steam-wont-start). Is there anything else after the line `Installing breakpad...`?

Comment: There is nothing after the line about installing breakpad

Comment: Oh, it works now. Have no idea what I did, but it works now

Answer (score 2):

Well, I used

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

and it didn't seem to work, but when I ran steam, it started up.
I have no idea how trying to install a package that it said didn't exist worked, but apparently it does.

Comment: Great. You can also [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) in 48 hours.

Comment: Well, now steam doesn't work again, because I switched out my graphics card for an AMD Radeon Sapphire card, so what do I do now?