# Steam Refuses to Launch on Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit

Tags: steam, 15.04

So I recently downloaded and installed Steam on Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit. However, when I attempt to launch it, it crashes. Heres my terminal:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0_client)
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/crash_20150502215003_1.dmp
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = no
error: libcurl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/home/user123/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 730:  8648 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
mv: cannot stat ‘/home/user123/.steam/registry.vdf’: No such file or directory
Installing bootstrap /home/user123/.local/share/Steam/bootstrap.tar.xz
Reset complete!
Restarting Steam by request...
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/user123/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0_client)
Uploading dump (out-of-process) [proxy '']
/tmp/dumps/crash_20150502215004_1.dmp
Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = no
error: libcurl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/home/user123/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 730:  8774 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
```

I am running the AMD proprietary drivers. I have attempted uninstalling and reinstall Steam. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/517596/steam-wont-start-on-ubuntu-14-04-1/517605#517605

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the question: [Steam won't start on Ubuntu 14.04.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517596/steam-wont-start-on-ubuntu-14-04-1/517605#517605)

The steps described in the answers are:

1. Install `libcurl3:i386` as @CharlesGreen suggests in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/517605/77449):

   > `sudo apt-get install libcurl3:i386`
2. Follow @imolit's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/536280/77449):

> 1. uninstall your Nvidia or AMD driver
>
>    - I.e. `sudo apt-get purge fglrx*` or `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`
> 2. reboot
> 3. start Steam and let it update, while using the open drivers
> 4. reinstall your proprietary driver
> 5. and finally reboot again.

3. You can also try switching your driver to X.Org X server - see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/452596/77449) by @Michael:

> 1. Open Additional Drivers
> 2. Select "Using X.Org X server(open source, tested)" driver.
> 3. Then go to Ubuntu Software Center and install Steam (steam-launcher).
> 4. Then change Graphic driver back.

Comment: Number 3 did the trick. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: My pleasure! Thanks to @Michael for his answer :)